# Magento ver. 1.9.3.6 - oauth

Tags: magento-1.9, oauth

I've installed magento ver. 1.9.3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (Apache2, php 5.6.32).
I'm able to get SOAP api data using http://magento.local/api.php?wsdl=1
However, my need is to make REST api work locally as my customer uses it on prod.

POST http://magento.local/api.php?type=rest&products/oauth/initiate (with passed key and secret) returns 401 Unauthorized (oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_token).

I suppose, I'm using wrong path for the first step of oauth.
What is correct path for oauth/initiate ? 
Url http://magento.local/oauth/initiate returns 404 not found error.

Please advise.